# Show that the functions $m(x) = \inf_{a\leq \xi \leq x}{f(a)}$ and $M(x) = \sup_{a\leq \eta \leq x} {f(\eta)}$ are both continuous from left.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is defined and bounded on the interval $[a, b]$. Show that the functions 
$$m(x) = \inf_{a\le \xi \le x}{f(\xi)}$$ 
and 
$$M(x) = \sup_{a\leq \eta \leq x} {f(\eta)}$$
are both continuous from left.

Is it continuous from the right as well?

Comment: Take $f$ to be the Heaviside Theta on $[-1,1]$, which is 0 for $x <0$ but $1$ for $x\ge 0$, both defined and bounded. It seems that $M(x)=f$, but is clearly not continuous from the left at 1. Perhaps you have flipped the directions?

Comment: @VF1 The question is indeed saying from left, I have not mixed up

Comment: But do you agree that by your definitions for the Heaviside function $M(x)=0$ whenever $x<0$ and $M(1)=1$, so we do not have left-continuity, so the question is ill-formed?

Comment: @VF1 My understanding of supremum and infimum is not very firm, so I am not very sure, thats why I am asking here. But you might be right though.

Comment: @VF1 actually i can't really see why your example shows otherwise, i think one side continuity still hold for heaviside theta

Comment: How would you show that the Heaviside theta is continuous from the left at 1? It is not.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $M(x)$ is not continuous from the left, then for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for some $x,u \in [a,b]$ , if $0 <u-x < \delta$, then $|M(x) - M(u)| \geq \epsilon$.

Note that M(x) is a monotone decreasing function. Hence, if $u>x$, then $M(x) > M(u)$
Pick $\delta := \epsilon$. Then, if $0 <u-x < \delta$, we have $|M(x) - M(u)| \leq |M(x-u)| = |-M(u-x)| = M(u-x) = u-x \leq \delta := \epsilon$, which contradicts the assumption.

Hence $M(x)$ must be continuous from the left.

Since $m(x) \leq M(x) < \epsilon$, the case for m(x) also presents a contradiction. Hence, both M(x) and m(x) must be continuous from the left.

Comment: If $M(x)$ is not continuous from the left, then $\exists \epsilon >0\forall\delta...$, which is different from what you said. Further, $M$ is monotone increasing, not decreasing.

Comment: What if I the function is continuous?

Comment: The continuity of the function $f$ is a big assumption which was not stated in the question.

Comment: @VF1 I know since the question might be flawed, I am just trying to investigate what extra condition will make it work